# Spelling a word backwords

Tags: loops, for-loop, reverse, words, spelling

For all of the following words, if you move the first letter to the end of the 
word, and then spell the result backwards, you will get the original word:
banana dresser grammar potato revive uneven assess

I got the first part down, moving the first letter to the end, but I am not able to spell the word in reverse. I have to use a `for` loop for this, but I have no idea how to use it so it will spell the rest of the word backwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally the for-loop does not care in which way you modify the index, so you should be able to use something like

```
string firstAtLast = "otatop";
string reverse = "";

for(int i=string.length-1; i => 0; i--)
{
    reverse += firstAtLast.At(i)
}
```

Details for i and the string manipulation methods depend on your language of course.

Comment: What do you mean with "only C++"? I'm sure there are other languages that have an At method. Details on C++ strings an befound here for example: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/

Answer (score 0):

Why would you move the first letter to the end?

```
string word = "hello";
string neword = string.Empty;
Array a = word.ToCharArray();
foreach (char c in a)
{
    neword = neword + c;
}
```

I wrote that in C#, but its the same for mainly anything.

Actually, you might be able to do it this way if the language you are writing in is a bit smart:

```
string word = "hello";
string neword = string.Empty;
foreach (char c in word)
{
    neword = neword + c;
}
```

Comment: its a assignment given to me by my instructor. i have to be able to make them input word they like, then it will take the first letter and mover it to the end and spell the rest of the word, backwards.

Comment: so you actually have to get the first letter in the end?

Comment: well given that its an assignment the code me and #markus gave you are enough to finish it.

Comment: so basically if u spell dog = will be respelled as dgo. so the example was banana, it will spell the original word banana

Comment: no the code atm will spell god what i gave you is to take the word and reverse it.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick  (C#)

```
public void ReverseWord()
  {
    var word = "banana dresser grammar potato revive uneven assess";
    var length = word.Length;
    string reverse = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        reverse = word.Substring(0, 1) + reverse;
        word = word.Remove(0, 1);
    }
}
```

The result I'm getting is : ssessa nevenu eviver otatop rammarg resserd ananab